# How can I allow a profile to only have access to user creation and nothing else

Tags: security, configuration

I have cloned a read only profile and removed all access except manage users. I am still able to see custom code etc in set up and configuration. How can I restrict a user from accessing everything except user creation in set and configuration?

Comment: I don't think it helps if you ask this repeatedly https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303916/can-anyone-please-let-me-know-how-can-hide-everything-from-a-profile-except-us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manager user is dependent permission. Manager user can only be given if you have View Setup and configuration.

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?type=5&id=admin_users.htm

Which makes sense right? You can create/manage users from setup.

Comment: Ok...so does that mean if I am giving manage users , then other stuff in set up and config will also be accessible ? Is there any way I can create manager users as a tab altogether and use that and then remove all other permissions?

Comment: Not in Standard SF, You have to build custom UI, UX